# How merge two querysets from same model without ordering them

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have create two queryset from same model and merge them as a single queryset. But don't want doing any ordering on new created queryset. I want that my queryset elements listed as how i merged them.

```
queryset1  = modelA.objects.filter(id=modelB.rel_id)
queryset2  = modelA.objects.exclude(id=modelB.rel_id)
queryset = queryset1 | queryset2
```

I expect the output of should be

```
queryset = <QuerySet [<modelA: YY>, <modelA: XX>, <modelA: ZZ>]>
```

Because modelA: YY is a queryset1 and i merge it as a first element
But result was :

```
queryset = <QuerySet [<modelA: XX>, <modelA: YY>, <modelA: ZZ>]>
```

It ordering by modelA id again. Even i don't set any ordering in modelA and new queryset.

Comment: django querysets are lazy and don't execute until they have to. the merge operation just rewrites the executed sql to combine the 2 queries with no respect given to the merge order. the default ordering will be in effect unless you specify otherwise. If what you want is as simple as specific record on top, then just do a get on the id you want and put it at the top of excluded query set result. Or get the fullset and move it up to the top.

Comment: Just make `queryset = queryset1.exclude()`... why do you need the two querysets in the first place?

Comment: Also a merge of those two particular  querysets would just be all entities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [**`union(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union) function here, like:

```
queryset = modelA.objects.filter(id=modelB.rel_id).union(
    modelA.objects.exclude(id=modelB.rel_id),
    all=True
)
```

The [**or `|`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#or) on the other hand will, as the documentation says:

> Combines two QuerySets using the **SQL OR operator**.
>
> The following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> Model.objects.filter(x=1) | Model.objects.filter(y=2)
> from django.db.models import Q
> Model.objects.filter(Q(x=1) | Q(y=2))
> ```

That being said, if you want to specify the `modelB.rel_id` as last, you can do that as follows:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

modelA.objects.annotate(
    rel_to_b=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(id=modelB.rel_id),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('rel_to_b')
```

Here we thus annotate the `ModelA`s with an extra attribute `rel_to_b`, in case the objects are related to `B`, that attribute will be `True`, and since `True` is ordered later than `False`, that will be the last row.

This will produce a query that looks like:

```
SELECT model_a.*,
       model_a.id = modelB.rel_id AS rel_to_b
FROM model_a
ORDER BY rel_to_b ASC
```